# Load large amount of data (10000 signals - time series)

Tags: mysql, mongodb, cassandra, large-data, database

I am analizing how to store over 10000 signals 50 times per second. Probably I will read them from memory. Each signal has a timestamp (8 bytes) and a double (8 bytes).  This process will be running 4 hours 1 day a week. Then:

10000 x 50 x 16 = 8 MBS / seconds.

8 x 3600 x 4 = 115 GBS / week.

What database (or other option like files) should I use to store this data quickly. Are MondoDB or Cassandra good options? What language would be good? Is Java enough fast to read data from memory and store in the database or C is a better choice?

Is needed a cluster solution?

Thanks.

Comment: 50,000 updates/second is a lot -- but definitely feasible with enough hardware.  The choice of where to store the data, though, really depends on how you want to use it afterwards.  Why not just concatenate it onto flat files, for instance?

Comment: how many users will be using this database? Do you need your database to be network accessible?

Comment: The database is not needed to be network accesible. Flat files could be a good choise, thanks.

Comment: You could look into ways of compressing the data. The timestamps are probably almost the same for each signal. might be that the top bits compress well. Try putting the data in a zip archive as a first test. Also you might not need all the timestamps. Would it be enough to store 1 timestamp and then 1024 signals? this would halv the amount of data stored.

Comment: @EspenBrekke, I'd suggest to try Sqlite. It's very very fast and light footprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I'd suggest Sqlite database. It's very light weight and faster than MySQL and MongoDb.

See [benchmark](https://www.sqlite.org/speed.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

It is roughly 700~800 MB of data per single day - so if you need to query it - after one month- 25 GB will be scanned.

In this case you probably will need a clustered/sharded solution to split the load.

As data will grove constantly - you need to have a dynamic solution which can use  mongoDB shards and replica sets to span load and manage data distribution.